# Spring REST architechture - "expand" implementation

Tags: json, spring, rest, expand

I am developing a RESTfull Server with spring 3 and hibernate 4.

I need to implement an "expand" mechanism in order to support GET requests for the user resource.

Currently, when you do a GET request for a user you get the following JSON (via Jackson mapping):

```
{
href: "http://...."
name: "John doe"
age: "30"
userData1 : {
             href: "http://...."
             field1: "bla bla"
             field2: "bla bla"
             userData2 : {
                         href: "http://...."
                         field3: "bla bla"
                         field4: "bla bla"
                         userData3 : {
                                      href: "http://...."
                                      field5: "bla bla"
                                      field6: "bla bla"
                                      userData4: { //and so on with a real deep hierarchy
                         userData5 : {
                                      href: "http://...."
                                      field7: "bla bla"
                                      field8: "bla bla"
                                      userData6: { //and so on with a real deep hierarchy
              }} ...}
```

as you can see this is like an expand=ALL result. it has huge amount of information that most use-cases do not need.

Is there any generic library that can support an "expand" mechanism?
I wish my clients will be able to do GET user + expand="userdata1.userdata2.. etc.
and get only the relevant data and not all of it.

This example above is not really mirroring the state of my server, i have tons of complex objects with varying numbers (i.e userData3 can contain 5 complex datas: UserData4,UserData5,UserData6 etc.

I believe implementing is fairly easy without any generic solution, it will consume a lot of time tough and i don't have the luxury for it..

Any ideas on maybe creating a generic mechanism like this? maybe a usage of java.reflection is needed?  I really don't want a lot of if-else in my code \ hard coded stuff
any idea will help!

thanks!

Comment: Hey, I know this post is pretty old but I was wondering if you found a solution for this after all these years ? :D GraphQL is quite hot nowadays and does this out-of-the-box  but I'm trying to do resource expansion with a simple REST API